# How should I handle a duplicate answer by new user

Tags: discussion, flags, new-users, duplicate-answers

I was going though the Low Quality Post Review Queue when I came across an answer by a new, 1 rep user.

The answer is a copy of the code in another answer to a different question.  The user does provide a link to that answer in their answer so it is not plagiarism.

Normally I would comment saying they should flag to close as a duplicate but they can't as they only have 1 rep.  I was hesitant to do anything so I just skipped it in the review.

How should I handle answers like this?

<sup>I can provide links if needed but I didn't want to unleash the *Meta Effect*</sup>

Comment: Irrespective of the person's intents, the duplicated/copied content likely needs to be removed from the site.

Comment: @Makoto 2 questions. #1 Since when is duplication bad? #2 Since when is quoting stuff bad?

Comment: @Gudradain: Since I can't see the actual post, it's tough for me to comment on this specific issue.  However, speaking from experience, if one has posted the same answer on two different questions, chances are high that one is a duplicate of the other.  I'm not saying that it's *bad*, but it does split up information about the actual problem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd treat this similarly to the case where a new user posted an "answer" that is really a comment. If the answer is little more than a properly attributed copy of the other answer, I'd use a comment along the lines of:

> “Thanks for trying to contribute, but you aren't following the rules of the site.  Instead of adding another copy of an existing answer, you should instead flag this question as a duplicate of the one where you found this answer.  You will be able to do this once you have sufficient reputation to comment on any post.  In the meantime, please refrain from posting these kinds of answers.  If you have additional insights into the problem, you can answer the question where you found the solution.”

Then I'd recommend deletion for the answer and flag the question as a duplicate.  Remember that not being able to do the best thing is no excuse for doing the wrong thing.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly how I handle this, barring the details of wording the auto-comment.

Comment: Thanks.  I am going to barrow from your comment.  I am not going to flag this as a duplicate though as I am not a 100% sure if they are.  Both question have multiple different answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's fair.  Yeah feel free to take whatever aspect of my suggested comments that you want.

Comment: I don't see the harm in just flagging the question as a duplicate and leaving the newbie's answer alone for now (rather than discouraging him/her).

Answer (score 0):

New users should not get different treatment from long-term users. Ignore the fact that they are a new user and do the same as you would for anyone else.