# What would be a recommended/acceptable way to clean up duplicate answers in a single question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I work in [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) for most of my time on Stack Overflow.

From time to time, I see new answers being added to old, famous questions, which usually duplicate existing (accepted/upvoted) answers. Most of the time, these new answers don't bring any extra value on top of those existing answers and are often of low quality. Sometimes I see 10+ answers in a single question that duplicate a single answer.

A recent example: [MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 wont get fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763130/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127017-wont-get-fixed/78081955#78081955)

What I have thought of:

1. using the plagiarism flag: Trying to have a good faith, I don't consider a new answer plagiarism easily unless I spot a substantial amount of copied content. Usually, the poster may just overlook the existing answers, so I don't think a plagiarism flag should be used.
2. using the custom moderator flag: I believe this might be a better option than the plagiarism flag. However, I understand that there is quite a backlog in the moderator flag queue, and I am not sure if this is a good idea to add more loading to the queue. A single question may have 10+ duplicate answers and thus 10+ flags created.
3. downvote and comment: Credit to [@philipxy's link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255571/what-to-do-with-late-answers-which-retread-the-same-ground-as-previous-answers). I have tried that before in hope of the new poster cleaning up the answer themselves. Unfortunately, this is usually a futile act and doesn't receive any feedback from the new user.
4. duplicate answer flag: Credit to @phiilipxy again. There is a [suggestion on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243243/vote-to-delete-answers-as-duplicates-of-earlier-answers), but it is yet to be implemented.

I have checked out some relevant posts under the meta tag `duplicate-answers`, but those I found are rather related to a single user [spanning a single answer across multiple questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339180/deleted-duplicate-answers-policy) or [pointing out a question should be duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312776/how-should-i-handle-a-duplicate-answer-by-new-user), which I consider not applicable to my scenario.

So, what would be the general guidance to clean up these duplicate answers?

Comment: Re search success: Google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual & unreliable, read the help. (Old style is literal with some meta characters & bugs. You can sign up to get in line for the new AI search alpha--see meta Q&A & your [so] profile settings.) Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at meta.stackoverflow.com & [meta.se].

Comment: [What to do with late answers which retread the same ground as previous answers (but not as thoroughly)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255571/3404097) etc

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the duplicate suggestion first. For the first link I traced through the comments and seems it leads to a feature suggestion of duplicate answer flag, which is yet to be implemented. For the 2nd link your provided, I think it mentioned the usage of mod flag, which I explained my thoughts based on current situation in the question. Nevertheless, I do spot the suggestion of downvote and comment in both of your links. I have tried that before but some new users do not seem to circle back to clean up the answers on their own

Comment: Mod flag for deletion. Typically mods will delete. I usually downvote although I am loathe to waste rep on garbage. Doesn't matter much, downvote rep is returned on deletion--likely. Sometimes I comment, but again, so much garbage. "some new users do not seem to circle back to clean up the answers on their own" Ha ha. Good luck on that. But why do you think that matters? The posts are typically unsalvageable and anyway as is should be deleted. An answerer can always edit then flag a mod (to find a subject matter expert mod) to undelete. But improvement is typically difficult.

Comment: If you have the reputation you can also delete vote answers. Seeing the metric ton of duplicate answers on that question this may be necessary. What a mess.

Comment: "3. downvote and comment: Credit to @philipxy's link" The highest-voted & accepted answer there is, mod flag for deletion. PS See the Linked Q&A at that page. Eg [Should an answer get deleted if there's already same answer(s)? \[duplicate\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315375/3404097).

Comment: If I hadn't wasted downvotes on some of the endless stream of bad answers & answers to bad questions I'd already have the protect questions privilege & could block answers from users with under 10 reputation. Or if I hadn't stopped answering what I now see are confused and/or duplicate questions--essentially everything I see that I would answer if pinned down & clear, if not then a duplicate. Even when they're not duplicates people just won't make them clear.

Comment: "Typically mods will delete." My experience has differed.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is something similar to the problem where open source projects were/are getting bombarded with frivolous and often terrible pull requests. Because a pair of Youtube channels "educating" people in a particular country said that participating in open source could help them get jobs.

Comment: I've added a protect on that question as well, meaning that very low rep users (users that haven't earned 10 rep on [so] (doesn't include association bonus)) can't answer on it. That would have likely stopped at least 6 of those users posting an answer on that question.

Comment: Re *"this is usually a futile act"*: Yes, that is a consequence of the [Eternal September state](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/) Stack Overflow has been in for over 13 years (99% selfish users who will never give anything back, only take)